# Postgres relation does not exist when adding column to table?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm trying to create a schema and add tables to it via `node` using `node-postgres (pg)`. The  basic order of events is as follows:

```
1. Create schema
2. Create table in schema
3. Create columns in table in schema
```

I can verify that the schema and the table are being created without issues, but I get a `relation does not exist` error when trying to add the first column to the table. The query string for creating the column looks like this:

```
"ALTER TABLE " +
schemaName +
".process ADD COLUMN process_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('" +
schemaName +
".process_process_id_seq'::regclass)";
```

I've confirmed in the `console log` that the `schema name` variable matches what is was used to successfully create the table. Any ideas on why the error is being thrown here?

Comment: Does `process_process_id_seq` exist?

Comment: @stickybit it does not. I thought it was created in the code block defining the column. Does the sequence need to be created prior to creating the column?

Comment: Note that the code in the question and answer are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe can you expand on that?

Comment: Try with a `schemaName` that contains a double quote. Then your query will go boom or worse.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe is it still vulnerable if the `schemaName` is not a user input value? In this process there are a few chained APIs. One API gets a value from the database, which becomes `schemaName`, and adds it to the request body for the next API.

Comment: Nobody keeps a malicious user from creating a schema with a double quote in the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence needs to be created beforehand.

But you could also use the `bigserial` type which is a shortcut for a `bigint` column with a sequence and a respective `DEFAULT` created automatically. Something along the lines of:

```
"ALTER TABLE " +
schemaName +
".process ADD COLUMN process_id bigserial";
```

Maybe you fell over that. Later, when the table/column was created you cannot see the `...serial` anymore but the actual type and the `DEFAULT`.

More on `...serial` types can be found in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html).

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I initially set up a sample table in pgAdmin where I defined the column as `bigserial`. It looks like pgAdmin converts it to `bigint` if you look at the `CREATE` script that it generates (which I was copying before).

Comment: @userNick: It's not pgAdmin which converts it but the DBMS itself. But yes, afterwards you cannot see the `...serial` in the `CREATE` that pgAdmin creates but the real type and the `DEFAULT`.